Using Dlookup in Query to calculate within query
Table1 
DRank     |   Denom
Lt        |   40
CPT       |   91

Table2 
Name     |   Rank   |    Stat |   Percentage
Smith    |   CPT    |   10    | ??
John     |   LT     |   23    | ??

I am trying to calculate a field in the query in the calculated “percentage” field. The value is based on the Stat and the Denom. Im trying to calculate using dlookup but i keep receiving the object doesnt contain automation object errors”
Ive tried this:
Percentage: [stat]/dlookup(“Denom”, “Table1”, “[DRank] = “ & [Rank])

If i link the ranks in the query by adding the table it works but then I can edit data in the query. Any help would be appreciated!
Edit:
I just need to get dlookup to work in the query. This is the current attempt:
Denom: dlookup(“Denom”, “Table1”, “[DRank] = “ & [Rank])
Still displays an error that the object doesnt contain automation. Im wanting to show the denominator value (denom) in table1 within the query where the drank in table1 matches the rank in table2 in the query.

the formula that you used doesn't fit the pseudo formula value/ tptalsum Value * 100 so what result do you expect

I have the field set as a percentage. If i remove dlookup and just put in a number it comes out correctly. Even if i remove the whole formula and just have the dlookup in there, it returns the error instead of the denom value where DRank matches Rank.

Please edit the question and post the current  result and the wanted

Ok ive added an edit to the post. Im just trying the dlookup only and only getting an error still
